# Android Text To Speech Not Working w/ Japanese

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech

I'm using the example found at http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-using-the-text-to-speech-engine/

I've changed the `Local.US` to `Local.JAPANESE` and `Local.JAPAN` below:

```java
public void onInit(int initStatus) {

        //check for successful instantiation
    if (initStatus == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
        if(myTTS.isLanguageAvailable(Locale.JAPANESE)==TextToSpeech.LANG_AVAILABLE)
            myTTS.setLanguage(Locale.JAPANESE);
    }   
    else if (initStatus == TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Sorry! Text To Speech failed...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }   
}
```

The application runs fine and when set to Local.JAPANESE can speak English words just fine.

If I type in こんにちは into the bar and click the button, it makes a clicking sound. It doesn't show a Toast message saying it doesn't support the language.

Here was what is being outputted from logcat when I click with Japanese text:

```
W/patts   ( 1697): [verbalize_controller.cc:366] Failed to find verbatim rule for character 
W/patts   ( 1697): [verbalize_controller.cc:366] Failed to find verbatim rule for character �
W/patts   ( 1697): [verbalize_controller.cc:366] Failed to find verbatim rule for character �
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: are you sure that onInit is called before you click the button?

Comment: Yes. There is a section on the website explaining it. _Your class declaration is implementing “OnInitListener” so you must provide an “onInit” method. In this method, you can carry out any final set-up checks you need, as well as choosing settings for your TTS instance, such as language and locale options._

Comment: Sometimes onInit take a while before it finish, so I want to make sure that onInit returns before you click the button. If the toast "Sorry!..." is shown after you click, that means that onInit just finish at that time.

Comment: Just put a Log.d("tts", "onInit") on the last line of the onInit method and wait for it to show on the logcat before you type.

Comment: I'm seeing onInit in logcat before I type anything

Comment: And you still get error?

Comment: Maybe you check for the flag LANG_COUNTRY_VAR_AVAILABLE and see if it is available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most android devices do not come with Japanese language built in. You will have to install a third party language pack such as [SVOX](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.svox.classic&feature=related_apps#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEwOSwiY29tLnN2b3guY2xhc3NpYyJd). After installing it the next time you open your app it should prompt you if you want to use the android system or the new SVOX text to speeh. If it does not, you will have to change the default settings in app > language and input > text-to-speech. Once this is done it should be able to speak Japanese. You will not have to modify your code.

Comment: Thanks. After looking at the TTS settings only Spanish, French, German, Italian :\
Looks like I'll have to use a 3rd party one.